how to configure a container angular universal to work on a sub route in nginx reverse Proxy
I tried help of chatGPT and no sucess, i have many container where i want to use the same dns.
For exemple:
exemple.com/app1;

exemple.com/app2;

here my default.conf
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name exemple.ddns.net;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:40001/; # Frontend HTTP
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:40003/; # Backend HTTP
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name exemple.ddns.net;

    ssl_certificate /exemple.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /exemple.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://localhost:40002/; # Frontend HTTPS
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass https://localhost:40004/; # Backend HTTPS
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /jenkins/ {
        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_redirect          http:// https://;
        proxy_pass              https://localhost:57340/;
        # Required for new HTTP-based CLI
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_request_buffering off;
        # Required for WebSocket
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }

    location /portainer/ {
        proxy_pass https://localhost:9443/; # Portainer HTTPS
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /pihole/ {
        proxy_pass https://localhost:57346/; # piHole HTTPS
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
    
    location /angular-universal/ {
        alias /var/www/angular-universal/browser/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy_to_app;
    }

    location @proxy_to_app {
        proxy_pass https://localhost:40006; # Assuming this is where your Angular Universal app is running
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location ~* ^/angular-universal/(.+\.(?:js|css|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|ico|webp))$ {
        root /var/www/angular-universal/browser;
        try_files $uri $1 =404;
        access_log off;
        expires max;
}

}

on / i have a normal angular app
on /angular-universal/ i have another app
when i try to access /angular-universal/ the statics files dont load and when when i change routes it redirects me to normal angular app.
I want to access my angular-universal app on the sub route with working routes and static files.
What i have to do?
